# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'adversario_1' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-2.7

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
def aleatorio():
    from random import random
    a = random()
    return a
def torneio():
    canditado_1 = aleatorio()
    while canditado_1 <= 0.5:
        canditado_1 = aleatorio()
        if canditado_1 > 0.5:
            adversario_1 = canditado_1
    return adversario_1
```

Quando executo o código apresenta o erro:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'adversario_1' referenced before assignment

Já tentei fazer de tudo. Sei que é um erro de atribuição, mas não consigo resolvê-lo.

O que tenho que fazer para resolver?

Comment: Na função `torneio`, o que acontece se `canditado_1` for maior que 0.5? Não entra no `while` e é retornado uma variável que não foi definida. (*Obs.: Não seria candidato no lugar de canditado?*)

Comment: Sim é candidato, escrevi errado, Obrigado pela observação! Já corrigi.

Comment: Entendi sua explicação. Mas, como eu resolvo esse problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está na função `torneio`. É retornado o valor da variável `adversario_1`, mas esta é definida apenas dentro do `while`. Se, na primeira linha, `candidato_1 = aleatorio()`, já for sorteado um valor maior que 0.5, o `while` é ignorado e é retornado uma variável que nunca foi definida. Um erro lógico bem simples de corrigir: basta colocar a atribuição à variável `adversario_1` fora do `while`. Veja:

```
def torneio():
    candidato_1 = aleatorio()

    while candidato_1 <= 0.5:
        candidato_1 = aleatorio()

    adversario_1 = candidato_1

    return adversario_1
```

Neste [teste](https://repl.it/HSyx/0) executei a função 100 vezes e coloquei para exibir uma mensagem de erro caso o valor retornado fosse menor ou igual a 0.5, veja que nada é exibido, então temos a garantia que sempre o valor será maior que 0.5.

Um código um pouco melhor, implementando a mesma lógica, seria:

```
from random import random

def torneio():
    while True:
        candidato_1 = random()
        if candidato_1 > 0.5:
            return candidato_1
```

O resultado é exatamente o mesmo, visto que a função `aleatorio` pode ser substituída diretamente por `random` e o `while` anterior pelo loop infinito definido por `while True`. Este caso é mais indicado, pois faz apenas uma chamada à função `random`, enquanto antes precisava chamar duas vezes (redundância de código).

Comment: Sua explicação foi extremamente didática e resolveu o meu problema. Você está de parabéns!!